# How to limit database table size and rotate the data in MS SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

I am creating the database table for storing the logs or any data using ADO .net. I want, my table should have only fixed size of data, for example table size is 5mb. After that if any new data is added the old data/rows should be deleted.
Is this possible by some database table setting or by using query?
I am using MS SQL server for the same.

Comment: `for storing the logs.` what logs? What generates those logs? If you use a logging library it may have a setting to rotate logs. Otherwise you could create a job that drops old entries.

Comment: The question is a bit too vague to answer as it is. Logs are retained based on age or number of entries, not storage size. You can use table compression on the table to reduce its size if that's a concern.

Comment: This is not how databases are intended to work. And why such an absurd restriction of 5MB? That is tiny!!!! And at any size this is actually quite complicated when you have datatypes that allow for varying amounts of data.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : Thanks for the quick response. I am not using any framework. I am just adding the entries into database. If it is not possible on the size, can we do with rows count? For example I want to store only 1000 logs after adding 1001 log the 1st log should be deleted.

Comment: @SeanLange: 5MB is just an example. Can we do the same with rows count?

Comment: It seems to me that if you are wanting to limit storage space or rows in a table that perhaps a database is not the solution you want. That just isn't how databases work.

Comment: @SeanLange: Yeah that is why it is not common but it is an requirement. So I am looking for the solution. Thanks!

Comment: For this type of requirement I would suggest going with a nosql solution or something along those lines instead of a database. The amount of kludging and crazy stuff you would have to come up for such a strange requirement would be staggering. You would have to put triggers on literally everything to keep this thing under control. It would be a management nightmare. If the requirements for a max amount of disk usage and a max amount of rows is actually required a database just isn't the right tool for the job.